# Запрос, результат которого сгруппирован по одному полю и не содержит NULL значений

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Есть таблица Employers.
Нужно узнать ФОТ всех аналитиков и разработчиков в разрезе номеров подразделений и позиций.

```
+-------------+------------------------+----------+
| unit_number | position               | Salary   |
+-------------+------------------------+----------+
|           1 | Разработчик            | 50000.00 |
|           1 | Разработчик            | 55000.00 |
|           1 | Аналитик               | 60000.00 |
|           2 | Разработчик            | 45000.00 |
|           2 | Аналитик               | 64000.00 |
|           4 | Разработчик            | 50000.00 |
+-------------+------------------------+----------+
```

Чтобы получился следующий результат из 6 столбцов, unit_number не нужен:

```
+------------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+------+----------+-------------+
| position               |             | 1Sum      | 2Sum     | 3Sum | 4Sum     | SUM(Salary) |
+------------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+------+----------+-------------+
| Аналитик               |             |  60000.00   64000.00 | 0    |      0   |   124000.00 |
| Разработчик            |             | 105000.00 | 45000.00 | 0    | 50000.00 |   200000.00 |
+------------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+------+----------+-------------+
```

У меня почему-то не работают варианты вроде MAX(CASE) выдает ошибку синтаксиса и ошибка группировки.

```
mysql> SELECT position, unit_number, (CASE WHEN unit_number = 1 THEN SUM(Salary) END) AS 1Sum, (CASE WHEN unit_number = 2 THEN SUM(Salary) END) AS 2Sum, (CASE WHEN unit_number = 3 THEN SUM(Salary) END) AS 3Sum, (CASE WHEN unit_number = 4 THEN SUM(Salary) END) AS 4Sum, SUM(Salary) FROM Employers GROUP BY position, unit_number ORDER BY position;

+------------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+------+----------+-------------+
| position               | unit_number | 1Sum      | 2Sum     | 3Sum | 4Sum     | SUM(Salary) |
+------------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+------+----------+-------------+
| Аналитик               |           1 |  60000.00 |     NULL | NULL |     NULL |    60000.00 |
| Аналитик               |           2 |      NULL | 64000.00 | NULL |     NULL |    64000.00 |
| Разработчик            |           1 | 105000.00 |     NULL | NULL |     NULL |   105000.00 |
| Разработчик            |           2 |      NULL | 45000.00 | NULL |     NULL |    45000.00 |
| Разработчик            |           4 |      NULL |     NULL | NULL | 50000.00 |    50000.00 |
+------------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+------+----------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Если использовать этот вариант:

```
sum(case WHEN unit_number = 1 THEN Salary END)
```

то все равно получается таблица с `NULL`.

А мне нужно, чтобы получилось всего две строки: один Аналитик и один Разработчик.
А далее суммирование общих зарплат по юнитам.
И в последнем столбце по всем юнитам.

Comment: `sum(case WHEN unit_number = 1 THEN Salary END)` в принципе можно сократить до `sum(Salary * (unit_number = 1))`

Comment: Вот, только заметил, у вас же unit_number в group by, а его там быть не должно. Вам же надо что бы в одной группе оказались строки с разными unit_number. А group by показывает с какими одинаковыми значениями включать строки в группу. Во фразе select так же unit_number быть не может, потому что значений на строку несколько, а колонка под него одна

Comment: Ну вообще-то требуется сумма сумм, т.е. два уровня группировки. Так что группим подзапрос, дающий детальную таблицу с нуллями, ещё раз по position, суммируя зряплаты. И избавляемся от нуллей с помощью COALESCE.

Comment: @Akina Сумма сумм в данном случае просто обычный sum(Salary) без всяких условий. я никаких двух уровней не вижу